# Segmentation fault (core dumped) - C Error

Tags: windows-ce

Thank for your answers everyone, it works now

Comment: Use a debugger to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correctly pointed out by downhillFromHere, `teamtemp` should be of type `char *` and not `char`.

Do the following changes:

1) Change `char teamtemp` to `char *teamtemp`. Instead of storing a single character this will store string.

2) Change `char teamtemp=teams[j];` to `strcpy(teamtemp,teams[j]);`. To copy strings

OR you can also do following changes:

1) Change `char *teams[5]={"A","B","C","D","E"};`  to  `char teams[5]={'A','B','C','D','E'};`
Store values as char instead as array of strings.

2) Change `printf("%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%.2f\n",teams[j],player[j],goals[j],gamesPlayed[j],ppg[j]);`

to

`printf("%c\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%.2f \n",teams[j],player[j],goals[j],gamesPlayed[j],ppg[j]);`. Print the `char` values, as `teams` is now declared as array of char.

Comment: Thanks it works now! However although it works with the strcpy(teamtemp,teams[j]);" line instead, there is an error afterwards indicating that there is another Segmentation fault (core dumped) 
 error

Answer (score 1):

Your `teamtemp` should be of type `char *`, not `char`.

Comment: Thanks it works now! Im new to C programming, so what does the "*" help the program do?

Comment: Your variable `char *teams[5]` is an array of five strings, not five `char`s. Remember that in C, a string is represented by a pointer to its first `char`, which is therefore of type `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hunch that you know where the problem lies, try compiling the program using gdb. It will save you a lot of time, especially for segmentation faults.

Here is a really useful tutorial that I personally used myself when I was learning gdb: http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks, I will do that from now on, I didn't know about it before.

Answer (score 0):

As **

> downhillFromHere

** has pointed out the main error was that "char teamtemp" should have been "char *teamtemp" and now it works.